# Question about the sum of xi minus x bar square?

Tags: calculus, statistics

Im looking through my notes in class and see that it is written that $$S = \sqrt{\frac{1}{n-1}\sum(X_i - \bar{X})^2} $$ which is then equal to 
$$S = \sqrt{\frac{1}{n-1}\left(\sum X_i ^2 - n*\bar{X}^2\right)} $$

how is this possible? 
I tried expanding but don't see how it works

Comment: Note:  In order to be correct the second term should read $S = \sqrt{\frac{1}{n-1}\left(\sum X_i ^2 - n*\bar{X}^2\right)} $

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note: In order to be correct the second expression should read $$S = \sqrt{\frac{1}{n-1}\left(\sum X_i ^2 - n*\bar{X}^2\right)} $$

To see this we proceed by direct computation:

$$\sum (X_i-\overline X)^2=\sum X_i^2 -2\overline X\sum X_i+n\overline X^2$$

$$=\sum X_i^2-2n\overline X^2+n\overline X^2=\sum X_i^2-n\overline X^2$$

Comment: Just ahead of me ;-).

Comment: Makes a lot of sense. Thank you so much.